# Reactjs reaching child object elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, javascript-objects

What could be the problem with reaching child objects in react for this youtube-api obj.

Any ideas, why the .id.videoId is not reached ?
Tested props.videos and worked well, returning a obj to console.

Here is the code repo. You can clone it easily 
./src/index and 
./src/components 
https://github.com/antzu/Web/tree/master/src

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Please edit and post the actual code instead of images.

Comment: Looks correct...

Comment: Don't be _sorry_ for posting images instead of code: **don't do it**. Surely it is more effort than copy-paste-formatbutton?